# Windows 10 memory integrity doesn't start due to incompatibility

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, windows-defender, virtualization-based-security

I am using windows 10 v1809. Whenever I try to turn on windows memory integrity, I get an error saying that windows memory couldn't start because there MAY be an incompatibility.

I know that my computer is capable of running memory integrity as I have successfully turned it on in the past (using v1809). I suspect that it may be connected to the additional features that control panel offers because a long time ago when I successfully turned it on, I was messing around with those.

Does anyone know which ones need to be enabled or if there is something else that I need to perform?

Comment: Core Isolation Memory Integrity requires Virtualization enabled for your CPU in the UEFI firmware settings. Please add details about your hardware and BIOS/UEFI virtualization settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple windows reinstall fixed it. I have no clue as to what the error was, but everything works fine in windows 10 v2004.